# Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range with Conditional Format code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA (and any sort of programming in general), so I'm not sure how to proceed here.  I'm guessing my error has something to do with overlapping ranges for my conditional formats as I also got errors when the code was set up a different way that were resolved once the ranges no longer overlapped.  That might not be the case here, but I figured it'd be helpful to know.

I get a 'Subscript out of range' error with the following code:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim rngToFormat As Range
    Set rngToFormat = ActiveSheet.Range("$a$1:$z$1000")
    Dim rngToFormat2 As Range
    Set rngToFormat2 = ActiveSheet.Range("$k$20:$k$1000")
    Dim rngToFormat3 As Range
    Set rngToFormat3 = ActiveSheet.Range("$j$22:$j$1000")
    Dim rngToFormat4 As Range
    Set rngToFormat4 = ActiveSheet.Range("$i$22:$i$1000")
    Dim rngToFormat5 As Range
    Set rngToFormat5 = ActiveSheet.Range("$g$20:$g$1000")
    Dim rngToFormat6 As Range
    Set rngToFormat6 = ActiveSheet.Range("$d$9, $f$9")
    Dim rngToFormat7 As Range
    Set rngToFormat7 = ActiveSheet.Range("$G$3:$G$7,$G$11:$G$15,$E$3:$E$7,$E$11:$E$15,$N$3:$N$7,$N$11:$N$15,$L$3:$L$7,$L$11:$L$15")
    rngToFormat.FormatConditions.Delete
    rngToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=if(R[]C20=1, true(), false())"
        rngToFormat.FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = RGB(228, 109, 10)
    rngToFormat2.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=and(R[]C7=""6. Negotiate"", R[]C11<25)"
        rngToFormat2.FormatConditions(2).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    rngToFormat2.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=and(R[]C7=""4. Develop"", R[]C11<15)"
        rngToFormat2.FormatConditions(3).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    rngToFormat2.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=and(R[]C7=""5. Prove"", R[]C11<20)"
        rngToFormat2.FormatConditions(4).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    rngToFormat2.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=and(R[]C7=""7. Committed"", R[]C11<30)"
        rngToFormat2.FormatConditions(5).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    rngToFormat2.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=and(R[]C7=""Closed Won"", R[]C11<35)"
        rngToFormat2.FormatConditions(6).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    rngToFormat3.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
        Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:=200
        rngToFormat3.FormatConditions(7).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    rngToFormat4.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
        Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:=60
        rngToFormat4.FormatConditions(8).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    rngToFormat5.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=or(R[]C7=""1. Plan"", R[]C7=""2. Create"", R[]C7=""3. Qualify"")"
        rngToFormat5.FormatConditions(9).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    rngToFormat6.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
        Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:=0
        rngToFormat6.FormatConditions(10).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        rngToFormat6.FormatConditions(10).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 204, 255)
        rngToFormat6.FormatConditions(10).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    rngToFormat7.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
        Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:=0
        rngToFormat7.FormatConditions(11).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        rngToFormat7.FormatConditions(11).Interior.Color = RGB(215, 228, 158)
        rngToFormat7.FormatConditions(11).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
End Sub
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: which string exactly gives you an error?

Comment: I think you need to translate your formulas to A1 style (instead of R1C1).

Comment: @Peter Albert.  Hi, I get the error with both A1 and R1C1 style.  I'm using r1c1 because A1 style screws up the format range based on active cell.

Comment: @PeterL. The specific string it references is 
    rngToFormat2.FormatConditions(3).Font.ColorIndex = 3

I suspect the errors I'm getting might have something to do with format priority? Not sure I'm just sort of throwing out ideas

Comment: @PeterL. I tried adding priorities and got the same error, so scratch that as being the problem... I really think it has something to do with overlapping ranges but I have no idea how to fix it

Also, I tried separating each range into a different macro... when I run the macro for the 1st range it works, when I run the macro for the 2nd range, I get the same error and it screws up the format set by the first macro (for the 1st range)

Comment: which language version of excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You only delete the conditional formats for the first range - but add conditions to all ranges - and later access a specific one that most likely is not the one you just created (`FormatConditions(3)`)
2. The formulas you entered are the default english formulas - for some stange reason, `FormatConditions.Add` requires the local formulas though.

I reworked your code, take a look if it solves your problem:

```
Sub test2()

    fctApply rng:=Range("$a$1:$z$1000"), strFormulaR1C1:="=(R[]C20=1)", dblRGB:=RGB(228, 109, 10), blnDeleteOldConditions:=True

    fctApply rng:=Range("$k$20:$k$1000"), strFormulaR1C1:="=and(R[]C7=""6. Negotiate"",R[]C11<25)", intColorIndex:=3
    fctApply rng:=Range("$k$20:$k$1000"), strFormulaR1C1:="=and(R[]C7=""4. Develop"", R[]C11<15)", intColorIndex:=3
    fctApply rng:=Range("$k$20:$k$1000"), strFormulaR1C1:="=and(R[]C7=""5. Prove"", R[]C11<20)", intColorIndex:=3
    fctApply rng:=Range("$k$20:$k$1000"), strFormulaR1C1:="=and(R[]C7=""7. Committed"", R[]C11<30)", intColorIndex:=3
    fctApply rng:=Range("$k$20:$k$1000"), strFormulaR1C1:="=and(R[]C7=""Closed Won"", R[]C11<35)", intColorIndex:=3

    fctApply rng:=Range("$j$22:$j$10000"), strFormulaR1C1:=200, intType:=xlCellValue, intOperator:=xlGreater, intColorIndex:=3

    fctApply rng:=Range("$i$22:$i$1000"), strFormulaR1C1:=60, intType:=xlCellValue, intOperator:=xlGreater, intColorIndex:=3

    With fctApply(rng:=Range("$g$20:$g$1000"), strFormulaR1C1:=0, intType:=xlCellValue, intOperator:=xlLess, intColorIndex:=3)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(204, 204, 255)
        .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    End With

    With fctApply(rng:=Range("$G$3:$G$7,$G$11:$G$15,$E$3:$E$7,$E$11:$E$15,$N$3:$N$7,$N$11:$N$15,$L$3:$L$7,$L$11:$L$15"), strFormulaR1C1:=0, intType:=xlCellValue, intOperator:=xlLess, intColorIndex:=3)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(215, 228, 158)
        .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    End With
End Sub

Private Function fctApply(rng As Range, _
    strFormulaR1C1 As Variant, _
    Optional intType As XlFormatConditionType = xlExpression, _
    Optional intOperator As XlFormatConditionOperator, _
    Optional intColorIndex As Integer = -1, _
    Optional dblRGB As Double = -1, _
    Optional blnDeleteOldConditions As Boolean = False _
    ) As FormatCondition

    Dim objCond As FormatCondition
    Dim strFormula As String

    If blnDeleteOldConditions Then rng.FormatConditions.Delete

    strFormula = Application.ConvertFormula(strFormulaR1C1, xlR1C1, xlA1)

    On Error GoTo ConvertLocal
    If intOperator <> 0 Then
        rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=intType, _
            Formula1:=strFormula, Operator:=intOperator
    Else
        rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=intType, _
            Formula1:=strFormula
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set objCond = rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count)
    If intColorIndex <> -1 Then
        objCond.Font.ColorIndex = intColorIndex
    ElseIf dblRGB <> -1 Then
        objCond.Font.Color = dblRGB
    End If
    Set fctApply = objCond

    Exit Function
ConvertLocal:
    With Range("A1") 'change this to an empty cell address - it is temporarily used to translate from local to normal formulas
        .Formula = strFormula
        strFormula = .FormulaLocal
        .Formula = ""
    End With
    Resume
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this... this does indeed fix the issue and makes use of a few things I was unfamiliar with in VBA.  So, this not only resolves my problem but also provides a learning experience.  I am in your debt!

Comment: I do have one follow up question for you if you have a moment. 

Your code appears to set the proper range for the first condition (range a1:z1000) and then modify that range to omit i22:k1000 (omits columns i, j, k) when I don't actually want it to do that.  

Any info on how to change this?  I'll look into it to see if I can figure it out, but as I'm new to vba, I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Ah, my fault - I didnt see that the ranges overlap. I removed `blnDeleteOldConditions:=True` from all but the first call, that should fix it. Please don't forget to mark it as an answer, so the question gets closed.

Comment: I tried it with the modified code and now the 'Subscript out of range' error has re-appeared :(

Any ideas why?  Random guess, but would clearing all the ranges before adding the new conditional formats potentially fix this?

The error points to the 'objCond.Font.ColorIndex = intColorIndex' line

Comment: Will check in a few hours, only on mobile at the moment

Comment: No rush, I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Comment: I just re-ran the code and it did not produce any error. :-( did you do any modifications to it? What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately don't have rep to move this to chat so I'll have to update you here.  I made no actual changes to the code... just copy/pasted what you suggested.  No clue why it'd give me said error.  It still seems to have something to do with overlapping ranges on the formats.  Is there any way in the fctApply function to check to see if a range intersects and modify the range of the deleted format to avoid the intersecting range?

Comment: which version of excel are you using? if its 2007 or higher, the ranges can easily overlap... Try to run the code in an empty workbook and see if it runs there...

Comment: I'm running excel 2007.  The workbook in which I'm trying to use the macro is saved as 97-2003.  However, I tried running the macro on an empty regular excel 07 workbook and an empty 97-2003 workbook and got the same error (on both versions)

Comment: Just ran it on 2007 and can reproduce the problem. Seems like a 2007 bug as its working fine in 2010. Will investigate later tonight...

Comment: You're a boss Peter.  Thanks again for helping me out above and beyond

Comment: Okay, I really think this is a 2007 bug and don't know any further. I posted a new question that explains the issue a bit more at the core, take a look here - let's see if somebody else can help...

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I'll follow the other question thread to see if anything comes of it.

Comment: strange, seems like the link to the other question got lost. Here it is again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715989/conditional-formatting-of-overlapping-ranges-in-excel-2007-vba-bug

Comment: Hey Peter.  Thanks for the link.  I do want to let you know that I basically gave up on doing this through conditional formatting and just had the macro perform the functions the conditional formats were doing and highlight the ranges accordingly.  Seems like the simplest solution in this case considering the 07 bug we've found.